# Как слить несколько .gz архивов (gzip) в один не распаковывая их в bash?

Tags: linux, bash, gzip, archive

Как слить несколько .gz архивов (gzip) в один не распаковывая их?
Есть множество таких архивов, весят очень много, распаковывать крайне не желательно, при этом нужно объединить в один файл. При этом в каждом из архивов хранится таблица у которой есть header, хотелось бы сделать так чтобы в общем файле оказался header только первого файла чтобы такие header'ы доставшихся файлов не втречались где то в средине общего файла. Как написать пайплайн в bash? Я в нем не силен.

Comment: Просто соедините их в один архив более высокого уровня, используя [tar](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html)